# how to get a for loop to check if an input contains letters

Tags: python, for-loop

```
for letter in message:
    if letter.isalpha(letter)==True:
        positions = [(alphabet.find(m), alphabet.find(n)) for m, n in message]
```

This is the code I have so far but it gives me the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\new\Desktop\python\Part 2.py", line 28, in <module>
    if letter.isalpha(letter)==True:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'isalpha'
```

I'm basically trying to get so that it only does the positions part of the code if the first part is true.

Comment: you are testing `isalpha()` on a tuple, try this: `if letter[0].isalpha() and letter[1].isalpha():`

Comment: what is massage? can you give input?

Comment: can you give sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

May be you want `alphabet position` from `message tuple`. So, you can use **List Comprehension** for this. Like:

```
positions = [(alphabet.find(m), alphabet.find(n)) for m, n in message if m.isalpha() and n.isalpha()]
```

You can try this:

```
for letter in message:
    if letter[0].isalpha() and letter[1].isalpha():
        positions = [(alphabet.find(m), alphabet.find(n)) for m, n in message]
```

You can also try this:

```
 for letter1, letter2 in message:
        if letter1.isalpha() and letter2.isalpha():
            positions = [(alphabet.find(m), alphabet.find(n)) for m, n in message]
```